# c++ reading from cin

Tags: c++

If I have:

```
double x;
cin >> x;
```

then I proceed to enter a character or a string, what would happen? And what would the statement `cin >> x` return?

Comment: Seems like it would be a lot faster to just type that into a compiler to find out...

Comment: I'm getting weird errors via `cout << (cin >> x);`

Comment: that's because `cin >> x` evaluates to an `istream` which can't be used in an `ostream` (`cout`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `istream::operator>>` always returns an `istream` object, no matter what. The value of `x` however would be undefined, and the `istream` would be "errored" and wouldn't work again till you cleared the error state.

This is just from memory and I really haven't thought about this before, so if someone sees that this is wrong, I'll remove it.